# Come up with an algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Using only five 3s and valid mathematical operations, how to get answer 31? Only digit 3 should be there and you can use 5 times (no more or less) to get the answer.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to programming.

Comment: But I guess it would sort of algorithmic? Isn't it?

Comment: What Yu said, how is this a question?

Comment: This is not about programming or algorithms.

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question. If you post some code where you attempted to solve the problem and point out where it doesn't work, maybe somebody can help you. Also, you need to improve the title. As written, it does not contribute to the usefulness of the site to future visitors. (How will they know that the algorithm they need is the one you're asking about?)

Comment: From my personal opinion this question does not have any problem with tagging as algorithms. Because he/she asks a solution. For an example the given two answers (at this moment) we can analyse the efficiency. 33 - 3 + 3/3 uses lesser number of CPU cycles with respect to 3**3 + 3 + 3/3 (forgetting about compiler optimization and so on). He/she might be asking a better solution? Regarding title, around 99 per cent of us do not use 'correct' title. Moreover, correctness is too subjective. So, suggest you guys to move this from hold and let them to come up with better algorithms to calculate 31

Answer (score 2):

Would  this work?

```
33 - 3 + 3/3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get to 31 with…

```
(3**3+(3/3))+3
```

Comment: Why this is down voted? This is a correct answer. Isn't it?